# nltk not available for python 3.5.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk

I successfully installed nltk and works fine in python 3.6.3. I have to run a file where nltk was imported and tensorflow too ,hence, i have to activate tensorflow.

```
HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~$ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>
```

When I activate tensorflow seems to use python 3.5.2.

```
(tensorflow)HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~/AIG2018/Chatbot$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

When I look up for solutions this is what I tried but no positive results.

```
 (tensorflow) country_boy@Shikongo-Veijo-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~$ pip install nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
 File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
@_call_aside
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
callback(dist)
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
declare_namespace(pkg)
 File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
_handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
_rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/home/country_boy/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I think this has to do with pip. **The question is how do i install nltk in python 3.5.2??? Or how to i make everything work??**

Comment: Well i think the problem is that the `nltk` you first install is in site-packages of python 3.6.3 then you are importing it from python 3.5 you have to install nltk in that python 3.5 environment too.

Comment: How do i do that -https://stackoverflow.com/users/9400024/abdullah-ahmed-ghaznavi

Comment: well install it using pip in 3.5 environment or change the path to get that previously installed nltk for e.g `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<your_username>/Library/Python/3.6/bin` ***but first try to right `python3.6` instead of `python`*** in the line where you activate tensorflow i think this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you It works. thumbs.